# Filter RSS items with specific <media:thumbnail> attribute using SimplePie

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, simplepie

I'm grabbing an RSS feed, but I only want it to display items that include a specific image url inside the  tag. Here is the particular bit that I want to search for:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://media.publicbroadcasting.net/wfpl/events/images/ourPick5.gif"/>
```

And here's the specific code I'm using in this application. It's basic, and I'm not incredibly adept at Simplepie or PHP (I'm assuming there are more elegant ways of doing this for someone with a more robust knowledge of PHP):

```
<?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wfpl/.eventsfeed');
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :  
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5); 
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
endif; ?>

<ul id="events">
    <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :  ?>

    <li>
        <div><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></div>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Again, I only want to display the items with that specific image url in the "media:thumbnail" tag and discard all other items. And I don't need to display the image itself. I just want to use its presence as a way of deciding which items to filter out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check a certain url within a specified tag is in the parsing description, use preg_match(). In your particular case, change the part, `echo $item->get_description();` to

```
$strDesc = $item->get_description();
if (preg_match('/<media:thumbnail\surl\="http:\/\/media.publicbroadcasting.net\/wfpl\/events\/images\/ourPick5.gif".+?>/i', $strDesc))
    echo $strDesc;
```

[Edit]

I realized that the `<media>` tag is not in the `<description>` tag. In that case, this should work.

```
<?php 
include_once './inc/autoloader.php'; 
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wfpl/.eventsfeed');
$feed->enable_cache(false);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();


foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{
    if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure())
        if ($enclosure->get_thumbnail() != "http://media.publicbroadcasting.net/wfpl/events/images/ourPick5.gif")
            continue;
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></div>
            <div><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?
}
?>
```